# How we can verify manually hostname verify failed when calling to API with self sigh certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ssl, tls1.2

We have k8s service which call another service which run in another AWS account. The connectivity of both side are working without an issue. Sending curls request to the service will give expected result.
Recently required to connect to new API which has proper Route53 records, So we have change the old API to new API, but when service send request through application to the API, service is throwing an error by saying "hostname verify failed". I have downloaded and added the keys of the API service to the Java keystore. My plan is to run a pod+ container with some tool in same namespace and debug the error.
Is there way I can get same error with curl, wget or any tools ?
Also I have notice in the error, there are some url of "identity and access management" service.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Route 53, it sounds like the URL for the service changed, which is expected with the error you're getting - hostname verify failed.

The service you are connecting to needs to serve a SSL certificate with the new hostname. To see what it's serving, you can use the OpenSSL CLI:

`openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -servername cake.com -showcerts`
In this command, `-connect` should point to the server you want to connect to.
The hostname you are connecting to is `-servername`.

In your case, it sounds like they should be the same.

What you are expecting to see is a certificate where the `CN` or `subjectAltNames` includes the hostname you're connecting to. If it doesn't, you should adjust your certificate.

If you're having trouble generating the appropriate certificate, consider using something like [CNCF SPIRE](https://spiffe.io/docs/latest/spire-about/). To make it easy to get certificates in Kubernetes Secrets, you can use something like the [SPIRE integration operator](https://github.com/otterize/spire-integration-operator).